# It works fine in VSC, but in TestDome not passing JavaScript Test (Anyone tell what I have missed)

Tags: javascript

This is a TestDome JavaScript Test.

A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to undefined.

Implement the method isRepeatingPlaylist that, efficiently with respect to time used, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not.

For example, the following code prints "true" as both songs point to each other.

```
let first = new Song("Hello");
let second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");

first.nextSong = second;
second.nextSong = first;

console.log(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());
```

**This is my code:**

```
class Song {
   name;
   nextSong;

   constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

  /**
  * @return {boolean} true if the playlist is repeating, false if not.
  */

  isRepeatingPlaylist() {
     var newT = new Song(this.name)
     while (newT.nextSong = this.nextSong) {
        newT.nextSong = this.nextSong
        return true
    } return false
  }
 }

 let first = new Song("Hello");
 let second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");

 first.nextSong = second;
 second.nextSong = first;

 console.log(first.isRepeatingPlaylist());
```

**TestDome Test Link**: https://app.testdome.com/questions/javascript/song/48845

**Test:**

1. Example case: Correct answer (Pass)

Not Pass:

1. If playlist repeats, last song is followed by first song: Wrong
   answer
2. If playlist repeats, starting songs can be skipped: Wrong answer
3. Performance test on a large playlist: Wrong answer //

Answer (score 0):

```
isRepeatingPlaylist() {

    let songs = new Map()
    let s = this;
    while (s) {
      songs.set(s.name);
      s = s.nextSong;
      if (s && songs.has(s.name)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
     
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I took a different way. As we have to validate if any of the songs has the attribute nextSong as any song before the actual. I recorded an array of songs into a static array property.
In the end of the day, I found that is an executing error of the testdome page itself. Because it sets my "flag2 = false". I just runned my code here into stackoverflow, and thats it, I got a true results, exactly as in my console. Here is my code.

```js
class Song {
    name;
    nextSong;
    number;
    static instances = Array();

    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        Song.instances.push(this);
        this.number = Song.instances.length;
    }

    /**
     * @return {boolean} true if the playlist is repeating, false if not.
     */
    isInRepeatingPlaylist() {
        // Your code goes here
        var long = Song.instances.length;
        var flag1 = false;
        var flag2 = false;
        for (let i = 0; i < long; i++) {
            if (Song.instances[i].nextSong != undefined) {
                if (Song.instances[i].nextSong.number < Song.instances[i].number) {
                    flag1 = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (Song.instances[long - 1].nextSong.number == 1) {
            flag2 = true;
        }
        return (flag1 && flag2);
    }
}
let first = new Song("Hello");
let second = new Song("Eye of the tiger");

first.nextSong = second;
second.nextSong = first;

console.log(first.isInRepeatingPlaylist());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to undefined.

        Implement the method isInRepeatingPlaylist that, efficiently with respect to time used, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not.
        
        For example, the following code prints "true" as both songs point to each other.</p>
    <script src="song.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```